# Radio button is working but visually not checked.Can anyone explain how to fix it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have three radio buttons for creation, modify, and reject. The radio button for `Modify` is working but not visually checked. I did not get any problem like this when I'm doing same operation with same version of jQuery.

**Here's the code:**

```html
<div class="form-group col-sm-11">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Action to be performed<span style="color: red; font-size: 15px">*</span>:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3 select">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="radio" onclick="actionPerformInGroupTypeReg()" id="createGroupTypeAction" name="groupTypeActionRadioBtnGroup" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <label for="createGroupTypeAction" class="lableSize" style="margin-top: 3px">Create</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 select">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="radio" onclick="actionPerformInGroupTypeReg()" id="modifyGroupTypeAction" name="groupTypeActionRadioBtnGroup">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <label for="modifyGroupTypeAction" class="lableSize" style="margin-top: 3px">Modify</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 select">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <input type="radio" onclick="actionPerformInGroupTypeReg()" id="rejectedGroupTypeAction" name="groupTypeActionRadioBtnGroup" checked="true" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <label for="rejectedGroupTypeAction" class="lableSize" style="margin-top: 3px">Rejected</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What jQuery plugins are you using?

Comment: `checked="true"` should be either `checked="checked"` or just `checked`. Boolean attributes in HTML don't use `true/false` values.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: If that fixed it, I'll make it an answer

Comment: no it didn't solved the problem.